# Laravel Many to Many Relationship 5 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called Members, another called Awards and another called Events.

Each member can have multiple awards more than once and each award can be assigned to multiple members, these can be awarded on the members profile or as a result of an event.

**My member model relationship:**

```
public function Awards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Award', 'award_members', 'member_id', 'award_id')
                    ->withTimestamps()
                    ->orderBy('award_members.created_at','desc');
    }
```

**My relations table:**

```
Schema::create('award_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('club_id');
            $table->integer('award_id');
            $table->integer('member_id');
            $table->integer('event_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**My view output:**

```
@foreach($member->Awards as $a)
  {{ $a->title }} | {{ $a->pivot->created_at }}
@endforeach
```

**This outputs:**

- Award 1 | 12/08/2016
- Award 2 | 12/08/2016
- Award 1 | 11/08/2016

I'd also like to output if stored in the relations table the event name if it was added to the members profile via an event. the above only shows details of awards when added directly to the member.

**In my relations table an entry from an event would look similar to:**

- id = 4
- user_id = 1 (related to user table)
- club_id = 1 (related to club table)
- award_id = 3 (related to awards table)
- member_id = 1 (related to members table)
- event_id = 1 (related to events table but can be NULL)

How can I output when entered the event name?

Comment: could please elaborate what you want to retrieve ?

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to retrieve all the details related in relations table, on event name . right ?

Comment: @jaysingkar sorry, there are a few ways of giving an award to a member, either directly on their profile or from an event. If an award is given directly on their profile then no event id is stored, but when an award is given at the next event an ID of that event will be stored. What I'm trying to do is view all awards on the members profile in a foreach loop, if one of the awards was linked to an event then show the event name

Comment: ok. can you post your method where you are retrieving the data to pass into view

Comment: @jaysingkar sure, as all awards are related to a member it's $member = Member::FindOrFail($id); on a typical show method.

Comment: I mean how you are getting award details. like . 
`Member::FindOrFail($id)->awards()->get();`
something like this

Comment: `$member = Member::FindOrFail($id);`, this will only get you member, right

Comment: As the awards are related to member they are included in the $member model. In my view I output them like @foreach($member->Awards as $award) {{ $award->name }} @endforeach etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120852/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-wolrab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess when you have so complex a pivot, maybe it warrants being a model itself. In fact if you think about it, your `Award` is a type of award, which can be obtained many times in different circumstances. An award being granted to someone, at some moment, through some event, ... that's a different concept.

Say you are developing a system for a library. You would typically have a model for a book (title, author, etc.) and another one for "BookCopy" or "BookExemplar" which represents each physical copy of it. When a user takes a book, they really are taking the copy.

So I would say

```
// Member.php
public function Awards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AwardGrant::class);
}
```

---

```
// AwardGrant.php
public function Award()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Award::class);
}

public function Event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```